# Averaging over multipage TIFF pages in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, tiff

What would be the fastest/memory efficient way to get average over many frames of 16-bit  TIFF image as numpy array?

What I came up so far is the code below. To my surprise, method2 was faster than method1.

But, for profiling never assume, test it! So, I want to test more. 
Worth trying [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/)? I did not include here because after imstalling ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16 and MAGICK_HOME env var it still does not import... Any other library for multipage tiff in Python? GDAL maybe little too much for this.

(edit) I included libtiff. Still method2 fastest and quite memory efficient.

```
from time import time

#import cv2  ## no multi page tiff support
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
#from scipy.misc import imread  ## no multi page tiff support
import tifffile # http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html
from libtiff import TIFF # https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/

fp = r"path/2/1000frames-timelapse-image.tif"

def method1(fp):
    '''
    using tifffile.py by Christoph (Version: 2014.02.05)
    (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html)
    '''
    with tifffile.TIFFfile(fp) as imfile:
        return imfile.asarray().mean(axis=0)


def method2(fp):
    'primitive peak memory friendly way with tifffile.py'
    with tifffile.TIFFfile(fp) as imfile:

        nframe, h, w = imfile.series[0]['shape']
        temp = np.zeros( (h,w), dtype=np.float64 )

        for n in range(nframe):
            curframe = imfile.asarray(n)
            temp += curframe

        return (temp / nframe)


def method3(fp):
    ' like method2 but using pillow 2.3.0 '
    im = Image.open(fp)

    w, h = im.size
    temp = np.zeros( (h,w), dtype=np.float64 )

    n = 0
    while True:
        curframe = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(h,w)
        temp += curframe
        n += 1
        try:
            im.seek(n)
        except:
            break

    return (temp / n)


def method4(fp):
    '''
    https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/
    documentaion seems out dated.
    '''

    tif = TIFF.open(fp)
    header = tif.info()

    meta = dict()  # extracting meta
    for l in header.splitlines():
        if l:
            if l.find(':')>0:
                parts = l.split(':')
                key = parts[0]
                value = ':'.join(parts[1:])
            elif l.find('=')>0:
                key, value =l.split('=')
            meta[key] = value    

    nframes = int(meta['frames'])
    h = int(meta['ImageLength'])
    w = int(meta['ImageWidth'])

    temp = np.zeros( (h,w), dtype=np.float64 )

    for frame in tif.iter_images():
        temp += frame

    return (temp / nframes)

t0 = time()
avgimg1 = method1(fp)
print time() - t0
# 1.17-1.33 s

t0 = time()
avgimg2 = method2(fp)
print time() - t0
# 0.90-1.53 s  usually faster than method1 by 20%

t0 = time()
avgimg3 = method3(fp)
print time() - t0
# 21 s

t0 = time()
avgimg4 = method4(fp)
print time() - t0
# 1.96 - 2.21 s  # may not be accurate. I got warning for every frame with the tiff file I tested.

np.testing.assert_allclose(avgimg1, avgimg2)
np.testing.assert_allclose(avgimg1, avgimg3)
np.testing.assert_allclose(avgimg1, avgimg4)
```

Comment: [`pylibtiff`](https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/) will also let you iterate on pages in a multipage TIFF file, as will [`PIL.ImageSequence`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagesequence.htm).

Comment: Unless you really have many frames, and they are very small, looping in Python over the frames is not going to be a big factor in your running time. As you learned from method1, writing all the frames to memory at once turns out to be slower, even if the looping then happens in C. I don't think you are going to find anything working much better than your method2.

Comment: I should try pylibtiff. method2 seems good enough then. but this is what I wasn't sure so good to hear from others. Thanks!

Comment: I found pylibtiff little buggy for my files. documentation and project are out-dated (last updated 4 years back?) and the API does not match with doc. And, I get "unknown field with tag 51123 (0xc7b3) encountered" for every frame of my tiff file collected from MicroManager (ImageJ based app).

Comment: The easiest way is using **ImageMagick** from the command-line like this `magick image.tif -evaluate-sequence mean result.tif` If you want the fastest way, or most memory-efficient way, you'll need to provide a representative sample.

Answer (score -1):

Simple logic would make me bet my money on method 1 or 3, since method 2 and 4 have for-loops in them. For-loops Always make your code go slower if you have more input.

I would definitely go for method 1: neat, clear to read...

To be really sure, just test them I would say. If you don't feel like testing, I would go for method one.

Kind regards,